# How should we tag 'Hentai Ōji to Warawanai Neko.'?

Tags: discussion, tags

The series *Hentai Ōji to Warawanai Neko.* is a light novel series which is being turned into an anime this spring. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_%22Hentai%22_Prince_and_the_Stony_Cat.):

> ***The "Hentai" Prince and the Stony Cat.*** (変態王子と笑わない猫。 *Hentai Ōji to Warawanai Neko.*), also known by the shorthand **HenNeko** (変猫。) and **Towanai** (とわない), is a Japanese light novel series written by Sō Sagara and illustrated by Kantoku.

However, [hentai-oji-to-warawanai-neko](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hentai-oji-to-warawanai-neko) is too long (28 characters instead of 25). The English name, [the-hentai-prince-and-the-stony-cat](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hentai-prince-and-the-stony-cat) is as well (35 characters), even if we remove the "*the*"s (27).

Some suggestions:

- [henneko](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/henneko) or [hen-neko](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hen-neko) (from Wikipedia).
- [towanai](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/towanai) or [to-wanai](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/to-wanai) (from Wikipedia).
- [oji-to-warawanai-neko](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oji-to-warawanai-neko) ("The Prince and the Stony Cat").

It's worth noting that the word "hentai" is filtered by Google safe-search, which may come into play for reasons of SEO.

What should we call this series's tag?

Comment: Note that this discussion first came up in chat because I wanted to ask a question about this series.

Comment: If they use hentai in the context pervert, why not replace it with Pervert prince ?

Comment: @Dimitrimx Because it's unlikely that anyone who knows the show will think of it by that title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>After thinking about it overnight, I'm going to suggest [hentai-prince-stony-cat](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hentai-prince-stony-cat), which at 23 characters, just barely fits.</s>

Advantages:

- Fairly unambiguous.
- Catches all the important English keywords for SEO (even "hentai" though it will still be filtered if the person has safesearch enabled).
- Comes up if someone starts typing "hentai" which is the most likely way someone would look for such a tag, regardless of if they were searching for the Japanese or English title.

Disadvantages:

- We lose "and" and "the". The result is a minor grammatical abomination.
- This isn't any sort of official abbreviation. It's our own creation. I don't know if there's any sort of official policy regarding this, but it is a bit problematic in my opinion.
- We don't get any traffic from people searching for the Japanese title. In my experience that is more common than the English name. However, that's to be expected since the light novel community is quite a bit more fluent at Japanese than the anime community at large, and this novel hasn't been translated. There is no way that I know of to predict whether the Japanese or English name will be more popular in my opinion.

---

**EDIT**: In the past couple of days, I've seen quite a bit more news about this series. The common English-language sources seem to be using HenNeko as an official abbreviation. I think it's likely that this abbreviation will catch on in the English community in the same way that OreImo did.

My viewpoint is that if there's a common and official abbreviation, we should go with that when both the full English and Japanese names don't fit rather than making our own. This might hurt search traffic, but there's no perfect solution. For all we know it could help search traffic.

Hence, I've retagged my single question on the series as [henneko](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/henneko). I propose we make two tag synonyms in this case, namely [hentai-prince-stony-cat](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hentai-prince-stony-cat) (for those who know the series by its English name) and [hentai-oji-warawanai-neko](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hentai-oji-warawanai-neko) (an equivalent grammatical abomination in Japanese which barely fits at 25 characters).

A good tag wiki is a necessity in cases like this, so I'll write one in the near future unless anyone else does so before me.

Comment: I'm going with this for now. If someone else has a better suggestion in the future we can change it at that time.

Comment: I'm good with this also. Do we want any tag synonyms for this, though, since it's a bit of an odd name? Or is the tag wiki sufficient?

Comment: henneko seems fine.